# how do you create a menu item in the Ubuntu applications menu which changes the current directory before running a shell script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script

I'm looking to add a menu item to the applications menu in Ubuntu which will run a shell script. In order for the shell script to work I need to cd into the directory which contains the shell script. For example this works:

cd /etc/foo/launch.sh
./launch.sh

But this does not, assuming you're not already in the directory foo:

/etc/foo/launch.sh

How can I add a new menu item to the applications menu such that it changes to the directory /etc/foo before running launch.sh? I don't have permission to modify launch.sh. And I already tried this, and it doesn't work: Command: cd /etc/foo/launch.sh; ./launch.sh.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit dirty, but try this:

```
bash -c "cd /etc/foo; ./launch.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to create a script that does the `cd` and runs the script, then add that wrapper script to the menu.